# Creating a delegating authentication provider (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to create a Delegating authentication provider to do logic before deciding on which authenticationProvider to choose based on some arbitrary logic; for the sake of this example, if the username starts with a prefix.

My current SecurityConfig which will try the authentication providers one at a time:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final MyCustomCredentialAuthProvider myAuthProvider;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth
          .ldapAuthentication().configuration(...).here(...).etc(...).and() // ldapAuthenticationProvider is created here
          .authenticationProvider(myAuthProvider).and()
          // more authentication providers to be added in the future
    }
}
```

Based on the username, I would like to choose if I want to use try a provider, so they doesn't ever get invoked if the username doesn't start with a specific prefix ("ldap", "custom", "ad", "etc"...), so:

```
@Component
public class DelegatingProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    // Problem: How do I create this ldapAuthenticationProvider bean?
    private final LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider;
    private final MyCustomCredentialAuthProvider myAuthProvider;

    ...

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getName() == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("No username provided");
        } else if (authentication.getName().startsWith("ldapPlease") }
           return ldapAuthProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        // } else if (...) { ...
        // } else if (...) { ...
        } else { 
           return myAuthProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to wire in the LdapProvider in this manner as it gets created by the SecurityConfig - how can I create and wire in the LdapProvider bean when it was previously handled by the AuthBuilder in SecurityConfig?

Comment: Question, if you are just going to use the bean why don't you just @Autowired it?

Comment: @Jose Luis I'm struggling with how to instantiate the spring provided LdapAuthenticationProvider - every builder and constructor seems to be private and the builder pattern seems to heavily rely on the AuthenticationBuilder.

Comment: Can you please let me know if you have found any approach to instantiate LdapAuthenticationProvider?

Comment: @learner I'm afraid I did not, and I never found a solution to this problem

Comment: @TobiasRoland I just did that using reflection. Found no other solution while doing it without xml file.

Comment: Just feels so... hacky. Possibly a limitation of the spring framework we have to hack our way around, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthentication() {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer().configure(...).here(...).etc(...).build();
    }
    .....................................
    @Component
    public class DelegatingProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        @Autowired
        private LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private final MyCustomCredentialAuthProvider myAuthProvider;

        ...

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            if (authentication.getName() == null) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("No username provided");
            } else if (authentication.getName().startsWith("ldapPlease") }
               return ldapAuthProvider.authenticate(authentication);
            // } else if (...) { ...
            // } else if (...) { ...
            } else { 
               return myAuthProvider.authenticate(authentication);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);;
        }
    }
```

And as @NatFar specified

```
    @Autowired
    private DelegatingProvider delegatingProviderBean;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth
          .authenticationProvider(delegatingProviderBean).and()
          // more authentication providers to be added in the future
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you only add the delegatingProvider in configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)

Comment: @Isey How do you go from `new LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer().builderMethods()` to an actual instance of an AuthenticationProvider?

Comment: @TobiasRoland LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer#build() method creates LdapAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: Oh, it is private method, I see. You can try to invoke it via reflection.

Comment: any solution for instantiating LdapAuthenticationProvider object?